# Docker could not run

Tags: python, docker, bamboo

I tried to run the docker image by using the below command.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 application:latest
```

And it is runing , and returns the container Id, `00412bc8aabafa2e41943ee9422d3062661f375bb44d561e2c9326d2a3f83450`

And can not access the web project(Python Flask app).

Comment: I highly recommends you to go through this https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long string is the container ID. You can check if the container is currently running using `docker ps -a`

Comment: I can see the docker , but status is 'Exited (1)' . How do I solve this issue.

Comment: You can use the `docker logs container ID` to see what went wrong with the container and troubleshoot from there